# Cask 'restclient' definition is invalid: invalid depends_on key: ':java'

Tags: homebrew

when I using brew(`3.1.7`) update command to update my computer, shows this error:

```
Cask 'restclient' definition is invalid: invalid depends_on key: ':java'
```

then I tried to remove restclient:

```
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-cask on  master ⌚ 11:20:21
$ brew uninstall --cask restclient                                                                                                                                   ‹ruby-2.7.2›
Error: Cask 'restclient' definition is invalid: invalid depends_on key: ':java'
(base)
```

what should I do to fix it? This is my homebrew version:

```
$ brew -v                                                                                                                                                            ‹ruby-2.7.2›
Homebrew 3.1.7
Homebrew/homebrew-core (git revision 68bbba9239; last commit 2021-05-16)
Homebrew/homebrew-cask (git revision 559cb3b7d9; last commit 2021-05-17)
(base)
```

force uninstall still now works:

```
/usr/local/Caskroom/restclient/.metadata/3.7.1/20190625104811.510/Casks ⌚ 11:42:00
$ brew uninstall --cask restclient --force                                                                                                                           ‹ruby-2.7.2›
Error: Cask 'restclient' definition is invalid: invalid depends_on key: ':java'
(base)
```

remove the restclient folder still not work:

```
/usr/local/Caskroom ⌚ 12:40:16
$ rm -rf restclient
```

Comment: Did you post anywhere else? Sadly no response here. I have same issue. Can't be just us that hit this issue? Did you find any solution since?

Comment: Removing the restclient folder seemed to work for me.